# International Telephone Input - RegExp placeholder issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

If you select a country from the dropdown you will see that the number pattern for that country is formatted in the placeholder example. The problem is my current code shows the number as a string of `9` and has curly brackets for each pattern.

The desired placeholder shows when you remove the `RegExp` from the `var pattern`:

From:

```
pattern = telInput.attr("placeholder")
  .replace(new RegExp("[0-9]", "g"), "9")
  .replace(/([9]\d{0,10})/g, '{{$1}}');
```

To:

```
    pattern = telInput.attr("placeholder");
```

The placeholder then shows a DEMO string of numbers without curly brackets, which is the desired behavior. The only problem is now when I go to enter a value, the plaholder value is entered as the input.

How do change the code so that the placeholder shows the demo string of numbers (when `pattern = telInput.attr("placeholder");`) and when I keyup the input placeholder value is reset and the input I enter still follows that countries number pattern?

```js
var intlPhoneNumber = function intlPhoneNumber(countryCode) {
  // get the country data from the plugin
  var countryData = $.fn.intlTelInput.getCountryData();
  var telInput = $("#phone-number");
  var telInputLabel = telInput.parents(".form-group").find("label");
  var countryDropdown = $("#phone-number-country");
  var phonePrefix = $('.phone-number-prefix');
  var fullPhoneNumber = $('#phone-number-full');
  var errorMsg = $("#error-msg");
  var initCountry = countryCode || 'us';
  var pattern = '';

  //set initial pattern for formatting
  if (initCountry === 'us') {
    pattern = '({{999}}) {{999}}-{{9999}}';
  } else {
    // using as temp until formatting on init figured out
    pattern = '{{9999999999999999999999}}';
  }

  // reset function to reset error state on validation
  var reset = function reset() {
    telInput.attr("placeholder", pattern);
    telInput.removeClass("has-error");
    telInputLabel.removeClass("has-error");
    errorMsg.addClass("hidden-xs-up");
  };

  // populate the country dropdown with intl-tel-input countries data
  $.each(countryData, function(i, country) {
    countryDropdown.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", country.iso2).text(country.name));
  });

  // init plugin for formatting placeholders
  telInput.intlTelInput({
    allowDropdown: false,
    initialCountry: initCountry,
    utilsScript: "https://1cf5229636340d3e1dd5-0eccc4d82b7628eccb93a74a572fd3ee.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/testing/utils.js"
  });


  // set dropdowns initial value
  var initialCountry = telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").iso2;
  var dialCode = telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;
  countryDropdown.val(initialCountry);
  phonePrefix.text("+" + dialCode);

  // init format
  telInput.formatter({
    'pattern': pattern
  });


  // delete intl-tel-input items that aren't needed
  $('.flag-container').remove();
  $('.intl-tel-input').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('#phone-number', this);
  });

  // set placeholder
  telInput.attr("placeholder", pattern);

  // on blur: validate
  telInput.blur(function() {
    // reset states
    reset();

    if ($.trim(telInput.val())) {
      // if number is not valid
      if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
        // set hidden input to dial code + inputted number
        fullPhoneNumber.val(telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode + telInput.val());
      } else {
        // set error states
        telInput.addClass("has-error");
        telInputLabel.addClass("has-error");
        errorMsg.removeClass("hidden-xs-up");
        //clear hidden input val
        fullPhoneNumber.val("");
      }
    }
  });

  // on keyup / change flag: reset
  telInput.on("keyup change", reset);

  // listen to the country dropdown for changes.
  // updates placeholder and prefix when changed
  countryDropdown.change(function() {
    // Update Placeholder via plugin - so we can get the example number + format
    telInput.intlTelInput("setCountry", $(this).val());
    // Update Dial Code Prefix
    dialCode = telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;
    phonePrefix.text("+" + dialCode);
    // Use updated placeholder to define formatting pattern
    pattern = telInput.attr("placeholder").replace(new RegExp("[0-9]", "g"), "9").replace(/([9]\d{0,10})/g, '{{$1}}');
    // update formatter
    telInput.formatter().resetPattern(pattern);
    // clear telephone input to prevent validation errors
    telInput.val("");
    // update placeholder to specific
    telInput.attr("placeholder", pattern);
  });
};

// Testing for prepopulation. If country code not supplied: default = 'us'
// const initCountryCode = 'ca'; // uncomment to pass in as param
intlPhoneNumber();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/jaridmargolin/formatter.js/master/dist/jquery.formatter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://1cf5229636340d3e1dd5-0eccc4d82b7628eccb93a74a572fd3ee.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/testing/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/jaridmargolin/formatter.js/master/dist/jquery.formatter.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control" id="phone-number-country" name="phone-number-country" autocomplete="off"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="phone-number">
    <div class="form-control phone-number-prefix"></div>
    <input class="form-control" id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="tel" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="phone-number-full" name="phone-number-full" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the formatter curly braces before you add/update it to the placeholder. We can use a regex replace for that as well:

```
pattern.replace(/{{(\d+)}}/gm, `$1`)
```

```js
var intlPhoneNumber = function intlPhoneNumber(countryCode) {
  // get the country data from the plugin
  var countryData = $.fn.intlTelInput.getCountryData();
  var telInput = $("#phone-number");
  var telInputLabel = telInput.parents(".form-group").find("label");
  var countryDropdown = $("#phone-number-country");
  var phonePrefix = $('.phone-number-prefix');
  var fullPhoneNumber = $('#phone-number-full');
  var errorMsg = $("#error-msg");
  var initCountry = countryCode || 'us';
  var pattern = '';

  //set initial pattern for formatting
  if (initCountry === 'us') {
    pattern = '({{999}}) {{999}}-{{9999}}';
  } else {
    // using as temp until formatting on init figured out
    pattern = '{{9999999999999999999999}}';
  }

  // reset function to reset error state on validation
  var reset = function reset() {
    telInput.attr("placeholder", pattern.replace(/{{(\d+)}}/gm, `$1`));
    telInput.removeClass("has-error");
    telInputLabel.removeClass("has-error");
    errorMsg.addClass("hidden-xs-up");
  };

  // populate the country dropdown with intl-tel-input countries data
  $.each(countryData, function(i, country) {
    countryDropdown.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", country.iso2).text(country.name));
  });

  // init plugin for formatting placeholders
  telInput.intlTelInput({
    allowDropdown: false,
    initialCountry: initCountry,
    utilsScript: "https://1cf5229636340d3e1dd5-0eccc4d82b7628eccb93a74a572fd3ee.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/testing/utils.js"
  });


  // set dropdowns initial value
  var initialCountry = telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").iso2;
  var dialCode = telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;
  countryDropdown.val(initialCountry);
  phonePrefix.text("+" + dialCode);

  // init format
  telInput.formatter({
    'pattern': pattern
  });


  // delete intl-tel-input items that aren't needed
  $('.flag-container').remove();
  $('.intl-tel-input').replaceWith(function() {
    return $('#phone-number', this);
  });

  // set placeholder
  telInput.attr("placeholder", pattern.replace(/{{(\d+)}}/gm, `$1`));

  // on blur: validate
  telInput.blur(function() {
    // reset states
    reset();

    if ($.trim(telInput.val())) {
      // if number is not valid
      if (telInput.intlTelInput("isValidNumber")) {
        // set hidden input to dial code + inputted number
        fullPhoneNumber.val(telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode + telInput.val());
      } else {
        // set error states
        telInput.addClass("has-error");
        telInputLabel.addClass("has-error");
        errorMsg.removeClass("hidden-xs-up");
        //clear hidden input val
        fullPhoneNumber.val("");
      }
    }
  });

  // on keyup / change flag: reset
  telInput.on("keyup change", reset);

  // listen to the country dropdown for changes.
  // updates placeholder and prefix when changed
  countryDropdown.change(function() {
    // Update Placeholder via plugin - so we can get the example number + format
    telInput.intlTelInput("setCountry", $(this).val());
    // Update Dial Code Prefix
    dialCode = telInput.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode;
    phonePrefix.text("+" + dialCode);
    // Use updated placeholder to define formatting pattern
    pattern = telInput.attr("placeholder").replace(new RegExp("[0-9]", "g"), "9").replace(/([9]\d{0,10})/g, '{{$1}}');
    // update formatter
    telInput.formatter().resetPattern(pattern);
    // clear telephone input to prevent validation errors
    telInput.val("");
    // update placeholder to specific
    //telInput.attr("placeholder", pattern.replace(/{{(\d+)}}/gm, `$1`));
  });
};

// Testing for prepopulation. If country code not supplied: default = 'us'
// const initCountryCode = 'ca'; // uncomment to pass in as param
intlPhoneNumber();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/jaridmargolin/formatter.js/master/dist/jquery.formatter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://1cf5229636340d3e1dd5-0eccc4d82b7628eccb93a74a572fd3ee.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/testing/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/jaridmargolin/formatter.js/master/dist/jquery.formatter.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <select class="form-control" id="phone-number-country" name="phone-number-country" autocomplete="off"></select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="phone-number">
    <div class="form-control phone-number-prefix"></div>
    <input class="form-control" id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="tel" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="phone-number-full" name="phone-number-full" />
  </div>
```

Comment: The issue is with new country selections also. If you change the country it changes the number pattern and placeholder. If you remove the `.replace` that has the RegExp you can see the placeholder shows demo numbers in the selected country's pattern.

Comment: Thanks @wp78de

Instead of showing all 9's, the default placeholder provides a demo number for each pattern. You can see this if you remove  the `.replace()` on: `pattern = telInput.attr("placeholder").replace(new RegExp("[0-9]", "g"), "9").replace(/([9]\d{0,10})/g, '{{$1}}');`

How do I get the function to work without having to have 9's as the placeholder? It would be nice to have the demo numbers as shown when the `.replace()` is removed

Comment: @KyleUnderhill so, you do not want to set the generic pattern? Then, do not update it with the formatter pattern. Updated. You may have do define a fixed value for the initial number.

Answer (score 1):

Been searching for the solution for a long time, finally I found the options to customize/remove placeholder of intl-tel-input in angular..

Use `[enablePlaceholder]="false"` to remove placeholder.. Use `[customPlaceholder]="'xxxxxx'"` to customize placeholder..

You can <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd> to see more options of `intl-tel-input` in `ngx-intl-tel-input.component.d.ts`